# Unity Count Up Timer problems

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, timer

I am creating a game in javascript. I have a huge problem. In one of my scripts I make appear a character (in a random time). In the other script I want to make a count up timer starting when my character appears... This is the code I currently have...

My problem is that the counter does not start counting...

---

**Script on Character:**

```
//Shoot.js

#pragma strict
var inimigo : GameObject;
var minWait = 5.0;
var maxWait = 20.0;
//static var Shoot : boolean = false;
static var Shoot = false;

function Start () {
    inimigo.SetActive(false);
   Shoot = false;
    Wait();
}

function Update () {
    if (Shoot == true) {
        inimigo.SetActive(true);
    }
    if (Shoot == true && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        Debug.Log("It Worked");
    }
}

function Wait() {
    yield WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(minWait, maxWait));
    Shoot = true;
}
```

---

**Timer script:**

```
//CountUpTimer.js
#pragma strict

private var startTime : float;
private var textTime : String;
private var guiTime: float;
private var minutes : int;
private var seconds : int;
private var fraction : int;
private var textField : UI.Text;

function Start() {
}

function Update () {
    if(Shoot.Shoot == true) {
        startTime = Time.time;
        textField = GetComponent(UI.Text);
    }

    guiTime = Time.time - startTime;
    minutes = guiTime / 60; 
    seconds = guiTime % 60;
    fraction = (guiTime * 100) % 100;
    textTime = String.Format ("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", minutes, seconds, fraction);

    textField.text = textTime;
}
```

Comment: Who's starting Start()? Your <body> onload or something? By the way, you have 2 "Start" functions, perhaps thats the problem too...

Comment: @Saskia I think that both Start functions are in different scripts not in the-same script. Also the Start functions is automatically called by Unity once. The update function is also automatically called by Unity every frame. @ Pedro, why not do this with C#? You will save yourself so much time

Comment: Probebly faster too, Javascript sucks with timers, as specially if you need more than one, you have a problem...